# Prove $\frac{b-a+1}{ab} \leq \sum_{i=a}^b \frac{1}{i^2} \leq \frac{b-a+1}{(a-1)b}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, real-numbers

Given $b>a>1; \  a,b \in Z^+$. Prove $\frac{b-a+1}{ab} \leq \sum_{i=a}^b \frac{1}{i^2} \leq \frac{b-a+1}{(a-1)b}. \ $
I mostly care about the second inequality. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Your tags are in conflict.  How can "real analysis" and "algebra precalculus" both apply, for example?  What are you studying?  What techniques do you know about?  You have to give some context so we know hat kinds of answers are likely to be helpful to you.  Also, you should show us what you have done so far, and where you are getting stuck, so we know where you need help.

Comment: As you can see, this simple-looking inequality fits both tags. Also I made many failed attempts only, I have no idea if I made any "progress"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the second inequality just observe that
$$
\frac{1}{i^2} \leq \frac{1}{i(i-1)} = \frac{1}{i-1} - \frac{1}{i},
$$
hence
$$
\sum_{i=a}^b \frac{1}{i^2} \leq 
\sum_{i=a}^b\left(\frac{1}{i-1} - \frac{1}{i}\right)
= \frac{1}{a-1} - \frac{1}{b} = \frac{b-a+1}{(a-1)b}\,.
$$

The first inequality can be proved by induction on $b$.

Let $a\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ be fixed, and let us prove that
$$
S(b) := \sum_{i=a}^{b} \frac{1}{i^2} - \frac{b-a+1}{ab}\geq 0
\qquad
\forall b\geq a.
$$
If $b = a$ then $S(b) = 0$.
Assume now that the inequality holds for some $b\geq a$, and let us prove that it holds for $b+1$.

Using the induction assumption $S(b) \geq 0$, we have that:
$$
\begin{split}
S(b+1) & = S(b) + \frac{1}{(b+1)^2} -\frac{b-a+2}{a(b+1)} + \frac{b-a+1}{ab}
\\ & \geq \frac{1}{(b+1)^2} -\frac{b-a+2}{a(b+1)} + \frac{b-a+1}{ab}
\\ & =
\frac{b-a+1}{ab(b+1)^2} > 0.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much sir! The second inequality indeed works. But using the same technique in the first one, it seems we can only get a weaker result. Can you elaborate on how to prove the first inequality please?

Comment: You are right. Using the same argument, at the denominator you obtain $a(b+1)$.

Comment: Right, I'm just curious how to prove the stronger ($ab$ on denominator) inequality.

Comment: I have added a proof of the first inequality.

Comment: Wow that works. Thank you!